# Combine a running balance SQL statement as a column

Tags: ms-access

I have two Select Statements which are collecting data from 1 table, one is a totals select statement. Could anyone assist me with combining them into 1 statement? Any assistance is appreciated

Statement 1

```
SELECT ClientId, ExternalBank, PlacementDate
FROM tblDepositTransactions where ID = 15
```

Statement 2

```
SELECT Sum(EffectiveAmount) AS RunningBalance
FROM tblDepositTransactions WHERE ID = 15 GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that with MS Access (its missing the support for window functions). You will need to write a program for that

Comment: I meant a combined SQL statement not as a recordset

Comment: Yes I understand that, you are looking for something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69045/1 but that is not possible with MS Access

Comment: As MS Access doesn't have window functions, maybe this would work there: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69045/2 (I neither know nor use MS Access so I can't tell if that sub-select would work there)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I got a way of doing it, treating it the same way as a fixed number eg If I wanted to add the number 017 to every row.

    SELECT ClientId, ExternalBank, PlacementDate,(SELECT Sum(EffectiveAmount)
    FROM tblDepositTransactions WHERE ID = 15 GROUP BY ID)as RunningBalance
    FROM tblDepositTransactions where ID = 15